# Conexión de base de datos Identity y Entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy ocupando Identity para la  autenticación del usuario. En base a eso, ocupé esa base de datos para colocar más tablas y campos (a modo de prueba). A su vez, usando entity, importé la base de datos (la anterior). Resulta que cuando quiero crear un nuevo usuario, esta se guarda en la primera base de datos, como puedo conectar la creación de usuario a la base de datos que importé con entity? en simples palabras, quiero que el registro se guarde en la segunda base de datos(reitoro, tiene las mismas tablas y campos de la primera base de datos), como se hace? Dejo el web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<configSections>

<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProyectoBase4-20190320081106.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProyectoBase4-20190320081106;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="EntitiesPortal" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=PortalEmpleoDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
 <appSettings> ...
```

Gracias de antemano :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De tus dos cadenas de conexión necesitas elegir la correcta para tu base de datos a la que quieres apuntar.

Checa cual es la correcta y actualiza la otra para que apunte a la base de datos. Fijate en especial al valor de 'Initial Catalog', ahí encontraras la que realmente necesitas.

Según entiendo deberias tener para las dos algo como:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=PortalEmpleoDB;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="EntitiesPortal" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelPortalEmpleoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=PortalEmpleoDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Me salvaste la vida !, he estado esto hace rato y no me funcionaba, pero ahora si. Resulta que en PortalEmpleoDB, se crean ofertas laborales, y debia anidarlo con los usuarios registrados, antes no se podía, ya que estaban separados, pero ahora si. Ahora me genera una duda... por que eliminas "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProyectoBase4-20190320081106.mdf;"? Ante todo, muchisimas gracias !